# How to send bulk data through Guzzle?

Tags: laravel, rest, guzzle

I am implementing an API that needs to receive data from my database. The data comes from my 'Products' table. I organized the products that I want to send through Guzzle.

```
public function post()
    {
      $product = Product::where('erp_status', '=', 1)->limit(5)->offset(0)->get();
        $client = new Client([
            // Base URI is used with relative requests
            'base_uri' => 'http://httpbin.org',
            // You can set any number of default request options.
            'timeout'  => 2.0,
        ]);
```

And right after I created a foreach to send the data through the URL.

```
foreach($product as $prod){
          set_time_limit(0);
          $r = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/items?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', [
              'json' => [
                  'title' => $prod->description->erp_name,
                  'category_id' => 'MLB46511',
                  'price' => 10,
                  'currency_id' => 'BRL',
                  'available_quantity' => 10,
                  'buying_mode' => 'buy_it_now',
                  'listing_type_id' => 'gold_special',
                  'condition' => 'new',
                  'description' => 'Teste',
                  'pictures' => [
                      ['source' => $prod->image->erp_image]
                  ]
              ]
          ]);
      }
      return view('home');
}
```

But every time I run. It returns the message:

```
cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 2012 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

My variable $product have 5 thousand rows.

Does Guzzle support this amount? Is it possible to use the guzzle in this case or what is the pure PHP script?

Any suggestion?

Comment: You should first check if the api allows posting multiple items. If so then chunk your results to the number of maximum items allowed and send it. This would significantly reduce the number of api request, time taken and resources.

Comment: The old programmers of the company did this function in PHP, the limit is double and works perfectly, I do not understand why Guzzle does not support.

Comment: You should turn this into a job and dispatch it to the queue to be executed in the background, in my opinion. Also with perhaps a small delay. Make sure you check to see how many API requests you can make within a given period of time to ensure that you're not exceeding that limit.

Comment: And let's say I want to order one at a time, can I do it through the foreach?